# How to bind Dictionary type parameter for both GET and POST action on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-views

I want to define a view which displays a list of label and checkbox, user can change the checkbox, then post back. I have problem posting back the dictionary. That is, The dictionary parameter for the post method is null.

Below are action method for both GET and POST action:

```
 public ActionResult MasterEdit(int id)
        {

            Dictionary<string, bool> kv = new Dictionary<string, bool>()
                                            {
                                                {"A", true},
                                                {"B", false}
                                            };

            return View(kv);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MasterEdit(Dictionary<string, bool> kv)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("MasterEdit", new { id = 1 });
        }
```

Beliw is the view

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, bool>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h2>
    MasterEdit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 

    <table>
        @foreach(var dic in Model)
        { 
            <tr>
                @dic.Key <input type="checkbox" name="kv" value="@dic.Value"  />
            </tr>


        }
    </table>


   <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Any idea would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use a dictionary for this. They don't play well with model binding. Could be a PITA.

A view model would be more appropriate:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        var model = new[]
        {
            new MyViewModel { Id = "A", Checked = true },
            new MyViewModel { Id = "B", Checked = false },
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<MyViewModel> model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

then a corresponding view (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @Html.EditorForModel()
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

and finally the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/MyViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Checked)
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Id)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Darin Dimitrov, thank you for your advice. why do we need two ids on MyViewModel.cshtml?

Comment: @Pingpong, one is to display it as text and the other as hidden field so that it is sent to the server when you postback so that the view model is properly filled.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It works. What if the data passed to view from controller is a custom type that contains the collection. Thanks!

Comment: I found it: http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/2995732471/nested-collection-models-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) post by scott hanselman. There're the examples of model binding to a dictionary, lists, etc