# Pass Dictionary From Ajax to C# Codebehind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am using ASP.Net and jquery/ajax

I have the following script in jquery:

```
var sizes = [];
sizes.push({ key: "1", value: "3"});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pageUrl,
    data: '{"sizeList":' + sizes + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
}
```

This is the codebehind:

```
public static void AddProductToDB(Dictionary<String, String> sizeList)
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong as I have tried everything I could think of.
Thanks

Comment: what exactly are you having problems with? What errors, etc. are you getting?

Comment: I am getting the 500 Internal Server Error, but it is still not going in the method of the codebehind, and also the method is empty for now Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you've got other ajax posts working?

Comment: yes when I try to pass simple variables such as strings integegers and even arrays they all work

Comment: As per mvc model binding for dictionary [please have a look on this.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858061/how-to-bind-dictionary-type-parameter-for-both-get-and-post-action-on-asp-net-mv

Answer (score 2):

```
var param = {
    '[0].Key': '1', 
    '[0].Value': '3'
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pageUrl,
    data: param 
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it that way but it still gave me the same error. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am looking at this two years after it got posted but hopefully it will help someone if they stumble upon this post. I used the base of Damith's answer to form the parametes I was going to pass and got it to work by passing them the following way:

```
var param = {
    'filters[0].Key': '1',
    'filters[0].Value': 'test',
    'filters[1].Key': '2',
    'filters[1].Value': 'test',
    id: 1,
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
};
```

Then on the MVC code I had my method with the following signature:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexPartial(int id = -1, int? width = null, int? height = null, Dictionary<string, string> filters = null)
```

With these two things I was able to have the method detect the information passed as a `Dictionary<string,string>` and at the same time I was able to pass in additional parameters. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to use a page method. If so, you need to decorate your method (in code behind) with the WebMethod attribute

```
[WebMethod]
public static void AddProductToDb(Dictionary <string, string> sizelist){}
```

Then make sure you are posting the json object with jquery to the correct url...for example...PageName.aspx/AddProductToDb

That's all you need if you are using page methods

Comment: Hi my method already has that specification as other ajax methods are working the problem is when I try to pass the dictionary as a parameter

Comment: Got it. You are sending an object with a property (sizelist) that is an array, however,  the page method is expecting a dictionary.  What you have to do is create an object in your code behind with a property named sizelist that is an array of strings. Then decorate this object with DataContract attribute and the property with DataMember attribute.  That should do the job

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set traditional to true so it will serialize properly

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pageUrl,
    traditional: true,
    data: '{"sizeList":' + sizes + '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code. Make sure your method **"AddProductToDB"** has **HttpPost** attribute and **identical/same** name of the parameter in this case **"sizeList"**.

> **C# / MVC / Back End Side :**

```
[HttpPost]
public static void AddProductToDB(Dictionary<String, String> sizeList)
{

    //Business logic or Data

}
```

> **Javascript / jQuery / Client Side:**

And Enter the **URL** where you this function/method AddProductToDB.

For example "YourController/AddProductToDB".

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var sizes = [];
    sizes.push({ "Key": "key1", "Value": "value1" });
    sizes.push({ "Key": "key2", "Value": "value2" });
    sizes.push({ "Key": "key3", "Value": "value3" });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/YourController/AddProductToDB',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            sizeList: sizes
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
        alert("success");
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
var param = {
    '1': '3'
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pageUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify({sizeList: param}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("success");
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert("Status: " + textStatus);
    }
}
```

then you can read it from dictionary variable with this:

```
 public static void AddProductToDB(Dictionary<String, String> sizeList) {
     sizeList["1"]; // return "3"
 }
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.